# Opening a line ('o') auto-indents - how to avoid in a .txt file?

Tags: vim

Whenever I want to open a new line in Vim with <kbd>o</kbd>, it automatically indents (instead of starting at the beginning of the line). Why is that? How can I fix this?
(I don't want to switch off auto-indent, which is great for other file types.)

## UPDATE:

It seems to have something to do with the actual text: auto-indenting (`=`) the following two lines indents the second line (why? -- I would like both lines to start in column 1!)

```
*in golf: failing to make par is a loss, missing a birdie putt is a foregone gain, not a loss
*negotiations, especially renegotiations: concessions you make cause you much more pain
```

## UPDATE 2 (my .vimrc):

```
:set cpoptions+=$
:set virtualedit=all
:filetype plugin indent on
:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$'&&getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S'?'<1':1
:set fdm=expr
:set gfn=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 11
setlocal autoindent
setlocal cindent
setlocal cinwords=if,else,elseif,do,while,foreach,for,case,default,function,class,interface,abstract,private,public,protected,final
setlocal cinkeys=0{,0},0),!^F,o,O,e
setlocal nosmartindent " don't use smart indent option
```

Comment: Running Vim with a blank `.vimrc` (`$ vim -u NONE`) doesn't exhibit this behavior for me, nor does it happen with my personal `.vimrc`. My guess is that something in your `.vimrc` is making this happen.

Comment: Have you got `cindent` enabled, and if so what is the value of `cinoptions`?

Comment: @David: I've attached my .vimrc

Answer (score 1):

You can set options to take effect only for specific files. For example, I have the following in my vimrc:

```
if has("autocmd")
    augroup LISP
        au!
        au BufReadPost *.cl :set autoindent
    augroup END
    augroup C
        au!
        autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp set formatprg=c:\\AStyle\\bin\\AStyle.exe\ -A4Sm0pHUk3s4
    augroup END
endif
```

Using this, I can turn on autoindent, or file formatting, or whatever for the files where it makes sense, but not have it on generally, when it might annoy me in other cases. In this case, I turn on autoindent for .cl files, but not necessarily for others.

You could also, in theory, use the same thing to turn off autoindent for .txt files.